# Change text color when hovering border-bottom

Tags: css, menu, hover, border, stylesheet

I have this code, please observe this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/19/

When you hover over the words, the text color changes to white - which is how I want it. However, when hovering over the 20px border-bottom, the text color does not change to white. Just hover your mouse over the border-bottom and check.

How do I make so that the text color changes to white when you hover the bottom as well? I currently have hover settings on `ul#secondary-menu a:hover { color: #FFFFFF;}`

Comment: clean up unwanted HTML and CSS from your style.. very much crowded

Comment: Seriously? Pare down that CSS and HTML to just the required parts. Remember: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/); help us to help you.

Comment: Apologies, it is the stylesheet for my whole site. It is from a template that I bought so I am not entirely familiar with it as my coding knowledge is limited. So if I would remove things from it, I might end up removing something that would have been needed to solve this question. Maybe I should have added this note in the question...

Comment: Then that helps you work out where the problem is, we'll help you to solve your problems but we do require you to put some effort in to diagnose where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add (or amend your existing CSS to include) the following:

```
#second-menu ul.nav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VjhJ4/21/).

> Can you explain why it was not changing the hover previously and how this helped. As I mentioned, my coding knowledge is limited so I am trying to learn what the issue was here

It wasn't changing the hover effects previously because you'd, presumably (and I am presuming, I gave up reading your CSS less than half-way through), specified a `:hover` rule for the `a` element that was a child of the `li` element, but the border is attached to the `li`, not the `a`. So hovering over the `li`'s border had no effect.

This rule simply specifies that the colour of the `a` element within the `li` should be white (`#fff`) in response to the mouse hovering over the `li` element. In practice, placing this rule at the end of the stylesheet caused it to override any other conflicting rules that might have been declared elsewhere (and, once again, I gave up reading the stylesheet due to its length).

I'd recommend finding whatever rule you have that defines the `a:hover` effects, and add the two rules together, for example:

```
#second-menu ul.nav li a:hover,
#second-menu ul.nav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

The specificity may not need to be quite so high, so you might be able to reduce the selector, to something shorter like:

```
ul.nav li a:hover,
ul.nav li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Oh, and it's worth noting that you have quite a mix of in-line (`style="..."`) and external styles (using a stylesheet); try and use only the external form, for clarity and for ease of updating, editing and maintaining.

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you explain why it was not changing the hover previously and how this helped. As I mentioned, my coding knowledge is limited so I am trying to learn what the issue was here.

Comment: @Henrik notice how David put the CSS at the bottom of the stylesheet. This will give it higher prioritization over the other styles.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the border to be a part of the hyperlink (that is, the user can click on the hyperlink when the mouse is over the border), then you'll need to remove the border from the `li` and add it to the hyperlink instead. If necessary, add `display:inline-block` to the hyperlink.

If the border doesn't need to be a part of the hyperlink, then @David Thomas's suggestion should be all you need.

[Modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w73bK/1/)

Comment: Yes I would need the hyperlink to include the border as well, Can you kindly update the fiddle with your solution to this and I can have a look to understand what you mean?

Comment: I added a modified version of the demo. All I did was move the inline style for the border from the `li` tag to the `a` tag.

Comment: Worked perfectly, however, why is there a space between the blocks that get filled when hovering? It is around 1 or 2 pixels...?

Comment: Updated the demo again, removing `padding-right:2px` from the `ul#secondary-menu li` CSS rule for the `li` tags. If you need that extra spacing, add the additional 2px of padding to the `ul#secondary-menu a` CSS rule for the hyperlink tags.

Comment: Thank you, I have upvoted this although I couldn't accept it as the answer to this question as David already beat you to it. However, what you provided was most likely going to be my next question so thank you very much Matt ;)

Answer (score 1):

Search for the string 
ul#secondary-menu a:hover { color: #FFFFFF;}

in your css style and replace it with

ul#secondary-menu li:hover a{ color: #FFFFFF;}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, someone beat you to it, I have however upvoted this answer :)

Comment: thanks as when I posted the answer it was not there ... ;)
but anyway you got you got your answer :)